# Алгоритм accumulate для сложения строк

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как решить такую задачу:
Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку-запрос и множество стоп-слов и возвращает новую строку. В новой строке после запроса идут стоп-слова через пробел, перед каждым стоит дефис. Для этого нужно передать в accumulate четвёртым аргументом функцию, которая сворачивает множество стоп-слов в требуемый формат.
Мой код не работает:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;


string DushStopWords(string dush, string word) {
dush = "-"s;
return dush + word;
}
string AddStopWords(const string& query, const set<string>& stop_words) {
string result = accumulate(stop_words.begin(), stop_words.end(), query, DushStopWords);
return result;    
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно задание: ```передать в accumulate четвёртым аргументом функцию, которая сворачивает множество стоп-слов в требуемый формат```. И посмотрите на свою функцию. Разве она может обработать ```множество``` стоп-слов?

Comment: Да и, честно говоря, условие задачи для меня, например, так и осталось непонятным...

Comment: Я понимаю, что что-то не так в этой дополнительной функции DashStopWords, но что именно?

Comment: ЧТо касается условия:
На вход Подается строка для поискового сервера, допустим:
Help find error
А в догонку множество стоп-слов:
in, with, on, if, and
Нужно, чтобы выводилось так:
Help find error -in -with -on -if -and
одной единой строкой

Comment: Но тренажер на курсах мое решение не принимает. И ошибка там не конкретезирована. "Не правильно обрабатываются примеры из условия задачи" И все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну просто вы немного неправильно написали. Вам нужно чтобы к значению `dush` прибавлялось значение `word` после тире и возвращалась итоговая строка.

```
string DushStopWords(string dush, string word) 
{ 
    return dush + " -" + word;
}
// или так
string DushStopWords(string dush, string word) 
{ 
    return std::move(dush) + " -" + word;
}
```

Проверочный код

```
string DushStopWords(string dush, string word) 
{
    return std::move(dush) + " -" + word;
}

string AddStopWords(const string& query, const set<string>& stop_words) 
{
    return accumulate(stop_words.begin(), stop_words.end(), query, DushStopWords);
}

int main()
{
    set<string> stop_words{ "in", "with", "on", "if", "and"};
    string query{"Help find error:"};
    cout << AddStopWords( query, stop_words);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, все равно не работает.

Comment: Эти 2 функции работают, я проверил. Если у вас не работает, значит ещё где-то ошибка.

Comment: Ну, вообще, да
В online компиляторе вставил вот так:
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


string DushStopWords(string dush, string word) {
dush = "-"s;
return dush + word;
}
string query;
set<string> stop_words;
int main() {

string result = accumulate(stop_words.begin(), stop_words.end(), query, DushStopWords);
cout << result << endl;    
}
Все проходит нормально.

Comment: Не могу понять, как в комментариях корректно код вставить. Прошу прощения

Comment: Добавил в ответ проверочный код. В комментариях код одной строкой идет.

Comment: В вашем варианте переменная `dush` не используется, т.к. после входа в функцию ей присваивается новая строка `dush = "-"s;`, а старое значение затирается.

Comment: Вставил Ваш код. Выводится только одно слово -with
Странно, что даже не первое

Comment: Потому что код функции `DushStopWords()` вы не мой вставили, а свой. И в результате получается последнее слово из множества. А последнее оно, потому что при вставке множество сортирует элементы. Если надо сохранить порядок, используйте `unordered_set`, `list` или `vector`.

Comment: Все получилось!
Спасибо!
Но вот этой темы я не понял:
return dush + " -" + word;
Именно это решило все.

Comment: Ну пройдите пошагово. На первом шаге `"Help find error:" + " -" + "and"`. На втором шаге `"Help find error: -and" + " -" + "if"` и т.д.  P.s. спасибо здесь - принятый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря помощи @DmitryK удалось понять, что моя ошибка в коде заключалась в неправильном понимании работы алгоритма accumulate в **общем** случае, когда используется 4 аргумента, причем в качестве 4-го аргумента задействуется функция, которая **должна** указывать на используемую в данном случае операцию, даже если это операция сложения.
Я же в своем коде считал, что операция сложения при использовании accumulate должна применяться для всех его аргументов по умолчанию. Но таким образом accumulate ведет себя лишь в **базовом** случае, когда используются только 3 аргумента.
Поэтому, в своем коде я использовал операцию сложения лишь для прибавления символа "-" к стоп-словам.

Comment: `accumulate()` ведет себя одинаково. Просто в случае с 3 аргументами там операция по умолчанию - сложение, а с четырьмя - операция заданная пользователем.